# How to get value from select2 in Django

Tags: python, django, select

I am trying to add a new constraint, but according to the data, the code takes all values except acc_id4 and c_center, and the result is always something like

Row 1: acc_id4=None, description=salary 10/2023, doc=1023, d_date=2023-11-25, debit=1000, credit=0.00, c_center=None

I don't know why it's always nothing
Is the problem in the template or in the Django code? And how do I solve this problem?
Note: The JavaScript code creates a new row and makes the old row read-only. It also copies the values except for the acc_id4 and c_center values.
It also makes the generated name add a number after the _ sign.
[image]
html

```
    {%load static%}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Acc Entry</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'image/daleel.ico'%}" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static  'css\Entry.css'%}">
            <!-- Font Awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'%}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600&display=swap" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="radio">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" >
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">New</label>
                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" value="save" autocomplete="off">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Save</label>
                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio3" autocomplete="off">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">Edit</label>
                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio4" autocomplete="off">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio4">Delet</label>
                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio5" autocomplete="off">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio5">Search</label>
                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio6" autocomplete="off">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio6">Print</label>
                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio7" autocomplete="off">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio7">Posting</label>
                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio8" autocomplete="off">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio8">Option</label>
                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio9" autocomplete="off">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio9">Undo</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="playbtn" >
                <button class="play" id="first-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-backward-step"></i></button>
                <button class="play" id="previous-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-left fa-lg"></i></button>
                <div><input class="count" id="entry-count" readonly></div>
                <button class="play" id="next-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-right fa-lg"></i></button>
                <button class="play" id="last-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-forward-step"></i></button>
                <label class="post">post</label>
            </div>
            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'add_entry' %}" id="edit-form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="ehead">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3 no">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="id"  style="width:100px;font-size:16px;font-weight:450">Entry No</span>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control bg-white" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" name="en_id" id="en_id" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3 dt">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="id" style="width:100px;font-size:16px;font-weight:450">Date</span>
                        <input type="date"   class="form-control bg-white"  aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" id="date" name="en_date" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3 sh">
                        <input id="search-input" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search by name or account number"> 
                        <button id="search-button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                        <button id="Refresh" class="btn btn-secondary" title='Refresh'style="margin-left:2px"><i class='fas fa-sync-alt'></i></i></button>
                    </div >
                </div>
                <div class="acce">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <table class="table" id="Entry">
                            <thead class="table-success"> 
                                <tr class="thead">
                                    <th class="text-center tt" style="width: 2%;">#</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 20%;">Account</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 39%;">Description</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 6%;">Doc.</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 8%;">Date</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 7%;">Debit</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 7%;">Credit</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 5%;">Cost.c</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 3%;">add</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 3%;">Edit</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 3%;">Delet</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <div class="scroll">
                                <tr class="tbody">
                                    <td class="t11"></td>
                                    <td class="taccName">
                                        <select class="select-acc" id="accName" name="acc_id4_1"  style="width: 310px" >
                                            <option ></option>
                                            {% for cacc in caccs %} 
                                            <option  class="oaccName"  value="{{cacc.acc_id4}}">{{ cacc.acc_id4 }} ==>> {{ cacc.E_name4 }}</option>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </select> 
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="t1"><input type="text" class="form-control bg-white" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" id="description" name="description_1"></td>
                                    <td class="t1"><input type="text" class="form-control bg-white" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" id="doc" name="doc_1"></td>
                                    <td class="t1"><input type="date" class="form-control bg-white" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" id="mydate" name="d_date_1"  ></td>
                                    <td class="t1"><input type="number" class="form-control bg-white" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" id="debit" name="debit_1" value="0.00" ></td>
                                    <td class="t1"><input type="number" class="form-control bg-white" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" id="credit" name="credit_1" value="0.00" ></td>
                                    <td class="tcost">
                                        <select class="select-cost" id="cost" name="c_center_1"  style="width: 100px" >
                                            <option ></option>
                                            {% for cost in costs %} 
                                            <option  class="cost"  value="{{ cost.cost_id }}" >{{ cost.cost_id }} ==>> {{ cost.cost_name }}</option>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </select> 
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="t1">
                                        <a class="btn btn-primary text-center" title="Add row" id="add"  >
                                            <i class="fa-solid fa-plus fa-2xs"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="t1">
                                        <a class="btn btn-success text-center" title="Edit row" id="edit" >
                                            <i class="fa-solid fa-pen fa-2xs"></i> 
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="t1">
                                        <a class="btn btn-danger text-center" title="Delete row" id="delete">
                                            <i class='fas fa-trash-alt fa-2xs'></i> 
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            <div>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
                <!-- jquery 3-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js" integrity="sha256-JlqSTELeR4TLqP0OG9dxM7yDPqX1ox/HfgiSLBj8+kM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Bootstrap 5--> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Counter variable to keep track of row numbers
        var rowCounter = 1;
    
        // Function to make all input elements read-only and select elements disabled in a given row
        function makeInputsReadOnly(element) {
            element.find('input').prop('readonly', true);
            element.find('select').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    
        // Function to make all input elements read-write and select elements enabled in a given row
        function makeInputsEditable(element) {
            element.find('input').prop('readonly', false);
            element.find('select').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    
        // Function to validate the debit and credit fields
        function validateDebitCredit(element) {
            var debitValue = parseFloat(element.find("#debit").val());
            var creditValue = parseFloat(element.find("#credit").val());
            if (debitValue < 0) {
                alert("Debit cannot be negative.");
                return false;
            }
            if (creditValue < 0) {
                alert("Credit cannot be negative.");
                return false;
            }
            if (debitValue === 0 && creditValue === 0) {
                alert("Debit or Credit must be non-zero.");
                return false;
            }
            if (debitValue !== 0 && creditValue !== 0) {
                alert("Debit and Credit cannot both be non-zero in the same row.");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    
        // Function to validate the select fields
        function validateSelectFields(element) {
            var accNameValue = element.find("#accName").val();
            var costValue = element.find("#cost").val();
            if (!accNameValue) {
                alert("You must choose the account.");
                return false;
            }
            if (!costValue) {
                alert("The cost center must be selected.");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    
        // Function to destroy Select2 instances in a given row
        function destroySelect2(element) {
            element.find('.select-acc, .select-cost').select2('destroy');
        }
    
        // Function to add a new row
        function addNewRow() {
            var oldRow = $("#Entry .tbody:last");
    
            // Destroy Select2 instance in the old row
            destroySelect2(oldRow);
    
            // Clone the old row to create a new row
            var newRow = oldRow.clone();
            makeInputsReadOnly(oldRow);
    
            // Increment the row number in the names of relevant elements
            newRow.find('[name]').each(function () {
                var currentName = $(this).attr('name');
                if (currentName) {
                    var newName = currentName.replace(/(\d+)$/, function (match) {
                        return parseInt(match) + 1;
                    });
                    $(this).attr('name', newName);
                }
            });
    
            newRow.find('input, select').not('#description, #doc, #mydate').val("");
            newRow.find("#debit").val("0.00");
            newRow.find("#credit").val("0.00");
            newRow.appendTo("#Entry");
            newRow.find("#add").prop("disabled", true);
    
            newRow.find("#add").on("click", function () {
                var currentRow = $(this).closest(".tbody");
                if (validateDebitCredit(currentRow) && validateSelectFields(currentRow)) {
                    addNewRow();
                }
            });
    
            makeInputsEditable(newRow);
    
            var previousRow = newRow.prev();
            previousRow.find("#add").off("click").prop("disabled", true);
    
            // Initialize Select2 for the new row
            initializeSelect2(newRow);
    
            // Increment the row counter
            rowCounter++;
        }
    
        // Function to initialize Select2 for a specific row
        function initializeSelect2(element) {
            element.find(".select-acc, .select-cost").select2();
        }
    
        // Add an event listener for the initial "Add" button
        $("#add").on("click", function () {
            var currentRow = $(this).closest(".tbody");
            if (validateDebitCredit(currentRow) && validateSelectFields(currentRow)) {
                makeInputsReadOnly(currentRow);
                addNewRow();
            }
        });
    
        // ... (unchanged)
    });
    
</script>
<script> // make button save work1 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnradio2").click(function () {
            $("#edit-form").submit();
        });
    });
</script> 

<script>// make button save work2
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // ... your existing JavaScript code ...
    
        $('#btnradio2').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission behavior
    
            // Collect form data
            const formData = $('#edit-form').serialize();
    
            // Send a POST request to your server
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'add_entry', // Update with your correct URL
                data: formData,
                success: function (response) {
                    // Handle the success response, e.g., show a success message
                    alert('Entry saved successfully!');
                    // You can also redirect the user to another page if needed
                    // window.location.href = '/success-page/';
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    // Handle errors, e.g., show an error message
                    alert('Error: Unable to save entry.');
                }
            });
        });
    });
    
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Journal
from .models import D_Journal
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages
from accounts.models import Cacc
from cost.models import Cost



def journal(request):
    journal_data = Journal.objects.all()
    d_journal_data = D_Journal.objects.all()
    cacc_list=Cacc.objects.all()
    cost_list= Cost.objects.all()
    context = {
        'journal_data': journal_data,
        'd_journal_data': d_journal_data,
        'caccs': cacc_list,
        'costs':cost_list
    }
    return render  (request,'templates\entry\entry.html', context)

def get_journal_data(request):
    journal_data = Journal.objects.all()
    journal_list = []
    for journal in journal_data:
        d_journals = D_Journal.objects.filter(en_id=journal.en_id)
        d_journal_list = []
        for d_journal in d_journals:
            d_journal_list.append({
                "acc_id4": d_journal.acc_id4.E_name4,
                "description": d_journal.description,
                "doc": d_journal.doc,
                "d_date": d_journal.d_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),  # Format to dd/mm/yyyy
                "debit": str(d_journal.debit),
                "credit": str(d_journal.credit),
                "c_center": d_journal.c_center.cost_name,
            })
        journal_list.append({
            "en_id": journal.en_id,
            "en_date": journal.en_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),  # Format to dd/mm/yyyy
            "d_journals": d_journal_list,
        })
    return JsonResponse(journal_list, safe=False)

def add_entry(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                # Save Journal
                journal = Journal()
                journal.en_id = request.POST.get('en_id')
                journal.en_date = request.POST.get('en_date') 
                journal.save()

                # Save D_Journal rows
                for i in range(1, 10):  # Assuming a maximum of 10 D_Journal rows, adjust accordingly
                    acc_id4 = request.POST.get(f'acc_id4_{i}')
                    description = request.POST.get(f'description_{i}')
                    doc = request.POST.get(f'doc_{i}')
                    d_date = request.POST.get(f'd_date_{i}')
                    debit = request.POST.get(f'debit_{i}')
                    credit = request.POST.get(f'credit_{i}')
                    c_center = request.POST.get(f'c_center_{i}')
                    
                    print(f"Row {i}: acc_id4={acc_id4}, description={description}, doc={doc}, d_date={d_date}, debit={debit}, credit={credit}, c_center={c_center}")

                    # Check if any of the required fields for D_Journal is missing
                    if not acc_id4 or not d_date or not debit or not credit or not c_center:
                        break

                    d_journal = D_Journal()
                    d_journal.en_id = journal
                    d_journal.acc_id4 = acc_id4
                    d_journal.description = description
                    d_journal.doc = doc
                    d_journal.d_date = d_date
                    d_journal.debit = debit
                    d_journal.credit = credit
                    d_journal.c_center = c_center
                    d_journal.save()

                messages.success(request, 'Entry added successfully!')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('journal')
        except Exception as e:
            messages.error(request, f'Error: {e}')
            return render(request, 'templates\\entry\\entry.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'templates\\entry\\entry.html')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from datetime import date
from accounts.models import Cacc
from cost.models import Cost
class Journal(models.Model):
    en_id = models.IntegerField (primary_key=True)
    en_date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=date.today)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.en_id}'
        
class D_Journal(models.Model):
    en_id = models.ForeignKey (Journal, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    acc_id4 = models.ForeignKey (Cacc, on_delete = models.RESTRICT)
    description = models.CharField (max_length=200 , blank=True)
    doc=models.CharField (max_length=8 , blank=True)
    d_date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=date.today)
    debit = models.DecimalField (max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)
    credit = models.DecimalField (max_digits=10, decimal_places=2 , default = 0.00)
    c_center = models.ForeignKey(Cost, on_delete = models.RESTRICT)
    def __str__(self):
        return f' {self.en_id} <==> {self.acc_id4}'
```

Comment: I can't see where the form is submitted.  That might help see why nothing is sent for aac_id4 and c_center.  However, the `.clone()` method will create a new row *with the same id*.  Perhaps that could be the issue?

Comment: @raphael the question has been edited and your inquiry has been added ,submitt by save button  i make it by javascript . Please support